# Why does substring extraction extract entire words instead of characters?

Tags: string, substring, zsh, parameter-expansion

Given a file `test.txt`, with the content `This is a test.` I want to extract a substring of its content, more specifically the second and third character ( `hi` ), using the command

```
echo ${$(cat test.txt):1:2}
```

However, this outputs the second and third word ( `is a` ) instead of the single characters.

I can do

```
a=$(cat test.txt)
echo ${a:1:2}
```

And it works as expected. But I want to do it in a single command.

Can someone explain what's happening here and offer a solution?

**Edit:**

The system is running zsh.

Comment: On my machine (Debian, with bash 4.4) this simply gives a ‘bad substitution’ error. It probably doesn’t officially work. For one thing, you use a $ (substitution) inside the braces in the first expression and not in the second.

Comment: You can not do a nested substitution in Bash. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189426/can-command-substitution-be-nested-in-variable-substitution

Comment: Sorry guys, I overlooked that the system was running zsh instead of bash.

Comment: @JimDanner you're right. Apparently zsh is the only shell in which nested substitution is possible, but I still don't understand why my way of doing it results in the observed behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Can’t explain exactly what is happening there, but you might use `sed` as an alternative:

```
sed -E 's/.(..).*/\1/' test.txt
```

which replaces every line with just its second and third characters.

Comment: I am trying to solve a hacking challenge and for this I can't use characters in [;|&`\'"]. That's why I wanted to use the substring expansion command